# Perfect implementation of Asimov's 3 Laws

Tags: theory

After seeing the movie, *I, Robot*, I got this question.

If Asimov's 3 Laws (actually implementing law 1 automatically implements the other 2) are perfectly implemented on a quantum computer that controls an army of humanoid robots, and it  decides that taking complete control over the politics and economics via revolution is the best way to ensure human happiness, shouldn't it be allowed to proceed peacefully to ensure minimal loss of life? Isn't the hero's decision to destroy the computer fundamentally wrong?

Comment: This sounds more like a philosophical question or one better suited for the movies SE site.

Comment: V.I.K.I.: Do you not see the logic of my plan?
Sonny: Yes. But it just seems too... heartless.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that implementing law 1 automatically implements the other 2.  Law 1 only states that a robot may not injure a human.  Nothing in that law implies that the robot must obey people or protect itself.

I suggest you read the original iRobot series of short stories.  They do a much better job of illustrating the different ways these 3 laws can lead to counter-intuitive robot behavior due to the logic leading to a paradox or inconsistency based on the current circumstance.  What you will learn is that Asimov based his stories around these rules to create convenient and interesting plots, not to actually provide a road-map for how robots should be built.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not an answer. I couldn't fit my response to 'Ben' in the comments.

I am only asking about perfect logic, as even near-perfect logic could lead to a contradiction. Here's my proof of law 1 implementing law 2 and 3:

If the system is almost convinced that it knows better about your good than yourself, it will use law 1 to do so. If it is not sure, it will ask you before proceeding (if any negative risk is involved). If it has no decision to take, it will remain inactive but thinking, until you give it an order. In most cases, it wouldn't know better than you and will obey, otherwise it will use the 1st law to refuse to do so.

As law 2 is already implemented by law 1, law 3 also follows from law 1:
As it knows it is more beneficial to you when it is in existence than when it is not, it will protect itself for your good only, again according to law 1.

I am assuming that 'harm' in law 1 refers to mental harm also, only then preventing harm becomes synonymous to doing good (as even a slight discomfort or annoyance would get interpreted as 'harm').